# form action not redirecting when submitted

Tags: php, html

still new to php but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with my form. It isn't redirecting to my php script when I hit submit. All files are in the same folder

reservations.html

```
<html>
<body>
   <h1>Reservations</h1>
   <form action="reservations.php" method="POST">
       <input id="city" name='city' type="text" placeholder="Airport Code or City"><br>
       <input id='submit' name='submit' type="button" value="Submit">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

reservations.php

```
<?php
   $city = $_POST['city'];
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
       print "<h1>$city</h1>";
   }
?>
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how this works but I thought it would change the url to server_url/reservations.php and display whatever I typed into the textbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your submit button must be `type` submit for it to redirect automatically.

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I complete forgot that was a type. I haven't used html in a while if you can't tell. That did the trick.